# How to do binding redirects for managed COM component server \ marshalling

Tags: .net, com, managed, assembly-binding-redirect

There are managed COM component server and client app (both written in C#).
Both are referencing the `System.Net.Http` assembly of version `4.2.0`.

When COM component created in client app (with a help of `CoCreateInstance` function from `ole32.dll`) and the function from it instance called I getting error attempting to cast the object returned to type from `System.Net.Http` of version `4.0.0`.

As according to modules window for client app(showing path to dll loaded which I open with ildasm to see the version) which loads `System.Net.Http of 4.2.0`and error

> {"Invalid HTTP status
>   code":"[A]System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue cannot be cast
>   to [B]System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue. Type A originates
>   from 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' in the context 'LoadFrom' at location
>   'E:\hws\src\Tools\VirtualPeripherals\ClientBrokerProxy\bin\Debug\net461\System.Net.Http.dll'.
>   Type B originates from 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' in the context
>   'Default' at location
>   'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Net.Http\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Net.Http.dll'."}

showing that COM component uses `4.2.0` looks like during marshalling there is attempt to cast the type using wrong assembly.

- How can I specify which assembly(`System.Net.Http 4.2.0`) need to be used during marshalling?
- If this not possible how can I express for COM component server that it need to use binding redirect(to `System.Net.Http 4.0.0`)?

Comment: Clearly you'll be much ahead here when you build the library with the 4.0.0.0 reference.  But the CLR looks for an appname.exe.config file, that can work well enough here since the client is a C# app for some reason.

Comment: @HansPassant sorry for misunderstanding, as far as I know appname.exe.config is about configuration for client, while error we see here is somewhat in the middle of client application and COM component communication, looks like it live in separate ComSurrogate process, so appname.config.exe won't work here.

Comment: That seems unlikely.  The only thing you can do wrong is not try it.

Comment: @HansPassant I meant I tried :) - if this configuration is for client app and should live in its folder, then it don't work for COM component server(I still getting the same error).

Comment: I also tried to change all References from 
<Reference Include="System.Net.Http" /> to <Reference Include="System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /> but it not compiles (error CS0433: The type 'HttpClient' exists in both 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' and 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a')

Comment: The only (weird and dirty) solution I found so far is to remove System.Net.Http v4.2.0 from folder of COM server and in its AssemblyResolve event handler return instead System.Net.Http assembly from GAC (4.0.0) + add binding redirect to 4.0.0 for client app (in its app.config)